# Java Google API oauth2 REDIRECT URI options

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am writing a desktop app using the Java API for google. I can authenticate using oauth2 and a REDIRECT URI of : `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` which will give the user a code to copy paste back into my application.

I would rather have a better workflow than that though, and replace the REDIRECT URI with `http://localhost:8080/myreceiver` - or something similar which I believe is valid.

My question is - what is the best way to easily bring up a Java based webserver at an address like that allowing me to automatically receive this code and continue oauth2 authentication?  Does part of the google api give anything to help here? Or should I be looking at a standard Java based web server like http://tjws.sourceforge.net/ or otherwise?

Any opinions would help me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I once developed an android App using Google OAuth 2.0, and I use special redirect_uri for installed App. When I send request with that special redirect_uri, it will display the code in title and body, just like the official docs says. But this doesn't make sense, because it's a bad user experience. So I write code in app to detect the page title and get the code automatically, it's easy, hope it's helpful.

Code:

```
if(view.getTitle().contains("code=")) {

webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

String title = view.getTitle();

    if (!handled) {
        new ProcessToken(title,oAuth2Helper).execute();
    }

} else

{
    webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: This would work on android but doesnt work the same on Java outside of android because you dont have API access to the browser window on the client's machine outside of Android.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to use tjws to launch a small web server which I was then able to write a little servlet which use the getParameter("code") method as part of the Servlet's doGet method to capture the callback code.

Pretty simple - and nice and user friendly.

Comment: You have a web server built in to Java so why not use that? Here is proof of concent that does the whole OAuth2 stuff with Strava. https://github.com/davidzof/strava-oauth/